# Bind failed when running but not when debugging?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

not sure how to troubleshoot this since when I set a breakpoint in my thread it executes as expected. However if I let i execute normally without any breakpoints, i ALWAYS get the following:

java.net.BindException: bind failed: EADDRINUSE (Address already in use)

It's a pair of UDP threads. One thread listens on a socket, the 2nd thread closes the socket used by the Listen thread, sends the packet and closes the socket. Listen Thread should try(and fail) to use the socket until it succeeds. There are no other threads accessing that socket and only 1 instance of each running.

```
public class Send implements Runnable{
    private MsgObj mo;
    private int i = 0;
    public void run(){
        while ( i == 0) {//I know this probably isn't the best way to do this, but don't know how else to do it. Any suggestions welcome :)
            if (!main.SendQueue.isEmpty()) {
                mo = main.SendQueue.remove(0);
                try {
                    listenRepeat = false;
                    String textString = Helper.msgCompiler(mo);
                    int msg_len = textString.length();
                    byte[] message = textString.getBytes();
                    DatagramPacket dPacket = new DatagramPacket(message, msg_len, mo.getIP(), mo.getPort());
                    if (!dSocket.isClosed()){
                    dSocket.close();}
                    dSocket = new DatagramSocket(3222);
                    dSocket.send(dPacket);
                    dSocket.close();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.getMessage();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else {
                try {TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);}
                catch (Exception e) {}
            }
        }
    }
}
public class Listen implements Runnable{
    MsgObj mo;
    public void run(){
        listenRepeat = true;
        while (listenRepeat == true) {
            try {
                byte[] message = new byte[1500];
                dSocket = new DatagramSocket(3222);
                DatagramPacket dPacket = new DatagramPacket(message, message.length);
                while (!dSocket.isClosed()){
                    dSocket.receive(dPacket);
                    String text = new String(message, 0, dPacket.getLength());
                    //do stuff
                }
                listenRepeat = true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.getMessage();
                e.printStackTrace();
                listenRepeat = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm very new and welcome any suggestions on how to accomplish my task better/cleaner. I'm sure there are many best practices I'm not following and will be grateful for any and all education.

Comment: This is all wrong.  Your sending thread should not bind to a specific socket, and should not close the socket being listened to.  This wouldn't even be possible if the sender and receiver were running on different systems. You should start by looking at the [Oracle datagram tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/clientServer.html)

Comment: This works with two android phones on the same network. I need to use the same socket for UDP Hole Punching. Unsure how I would listen and send from the same port without closing it